# Wake up ESP32 whith a sensor

Tags: c++, assembly, esp32, arduino-ide

So I am working with ESP32 which is powered by a battery, so I want it to wake up only if a sensor value is above a threshold. So basically if the ADC is above the threshold, it should wake up.

I found this resource online: https://github.com/gabriel-milan/esp32_ulp_hall_wakeup

Where he is using a Hall effect sensor value to wake ESP32 up from deep sleep.

I want to know what we can change in this code so that we have a generalized code for any sensor using ADC.

Comment: You need a sample code to wake up the ESP32 using a GPIO pin. If that's possible (I'm not so familiar with the ESP32 yet), you'll find information on this somewhere. What kind of ADC are you using?

Comment: [here is an example](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/system/ulp_adc)

Comment: I am using the Arduino IDE, how can I use the example provided?